# Windowing in frequency domain. how to cut a spectrum using window function in frequency domain?

Tags: window-functions

I have a set of measurement data of a FMCW radar and trying to estimate the system transfer function. In the frequency spectrum, I can see multiple peaks due to the non-linearity that exist in the system. I want to estimate the transfer function for each peak.

**What I did:**
I designed filters to cut out each peak and using deconvolution I've estimated the transfer function. In the verification step somehow this process has failed to replicate the system exactly.

**What I wanted to do:**
I want to directly cut out frequency peaks using window function instead of filters. But I am not able to understand how to place the window around frequency peaks so that I can extract each peak separately.

Comment: Hi Sanju, not quite sure what a "transfer function for a peak" is. Maybe sharing your plots with us and defining your problem mathematically would help?

Comment: Also, it's often a good idea to explain what "failed to replicate" means – what happened instead, how large was your deviation, what are your acceptable error bounds, and so on.

Comment: oh and windowing in frequency **is** convolution with the FT of the window in time domain, i.e. filtering, so I'm also not sure how you'd do one without doing the other, mathematically.